# flickr oauth api returns signature invalid error at random times

Tags: php, oauth, flickr, nonce

I have a web app that authenticates users to their flickr api. It makes use of OAuth 1.0 and authentication works most of the time. But at random times, at completely random times, flickr doesn't recognize my signature. It returns invalid signature error while requesting for a request token. But the same code in the next attempt would bring back request token properly.

I suspect that it has something to do with the way I generate nonce or time stamp. Otherwise it shouldn't work in the successive attempt, right?

This is how I generate nonce and time stamp values:

```
$nonce   = md5(microtime(true).rand());
$timestamp  = mktime();
```

Is there any problem in this? Are there any better ways to generate a nonce value? This random failure is very confusing. I can't think of any other reason why I'd get an invalid error, RANDOMLY!

---

**Followup**

As per Jan Gerlinger's suggestion, I changed mktime() to time(). It surely has reduced the  frequency of occurrences. But still it gives invalid signature error at random times, very rarely after changing to time(), I might add.

So, I'm assuming that timestamp(mktime) was one of the issues causing these random errors. But something else is still going wrong there. Maybe in nonce generation?

Comment: I would recommend logging all the requests and whether they succeeded or failed; then try to find a pattern from that.

Comment: @Jack I tried to figure out a pattern from it. But as I said, it occurs at completely random times.

Comment: Nothing is really random; if you're saying that the same exact nonce and time works at the second attempt, it could be something else altogether e.g. temporary server error.

Answer (score 4):

[Depending on your PHP version](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php#refsect1-function.mktime-notes), you should use [`time()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) instead of `mktime()`.

For the nonce, the [documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.3) says:

> A nonce is a random string, uniquely generated by the client to allow the server to verify that a request has never been made before and helps prevent replay attacks when requests are made over a non-secure channel.  The nonce value MUST be unique across all requests with the same timestamp, client credentials, and token combinations.

If [`rand()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) would return you the same value twice in a microsecond, you would get the same nonce twice. Also generating an MD5 hash does not guarantee you to get uniqe values because of MD5 collisions. The better method here would be to have a [global counter for the nonce](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/16/oauth-timestamps-and-nonces/).

If you get this error quite often however, the nonce is probably not your problem, as these collisions should not happen very often.

Sometimes the problem with *invalid signature* errors is that the client's server time differs from the provider's server time, so you could check if there's something weird happening on your server with time synchronization.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jan for that kind help. Let me try that. I'll get back with the result.

Comment: About that time sync; is there any way to ensure that my server time is in sync with the flickr server time?

Comment: Well flickr's servers are certainly synchronized using some NTP server, so the best thing you can do is use `ntpdate` or something similar to make sure your server is also synchronized. If you already do that you should make sure that nothing else is altering your server time.

Comment: Using time() seems to have helped to reduce the number of occurrences of invalid signature error. Thanks a lot. But still it shows error once a while. Could it be the server time issue you mentioned?

Comment: @goose To be honest, I don't see how using `time()` is better because in nearly all cases `time() - mktime() == 0`. Of course you should use `time()`, that's not the point.

Comment: Using `time()` should  make no real difference, I added it just for the sake of completeness. If you use a thread-safe global counter for your nonce and your server time is correct, then this problem is either a bug on flickr's side or something else in your code is wrong. But that are different issues, as your question was about timestamp and nonce. You could try asking for help directly at flickr's [API forum](https://secure.flickr.com/groups/api). They're probably the only ones that can say if this is a bug on their side.

Answer (score 1):

Without much more information I'd have to speculate it has something to do with the signature itself.

What I can tell you is that `time()` and `mktime()` are the same thing, so they're not your root cause.

I find that, on occasion, the signature may contain the base64 alphabet `+`. If that's not encoded properly, it might cause some issues; at the next request it may disappear and the request will pass.

If this is home brew code, I would recommend sharing that code and at the same time recommend you use a more trusted solution, such as the oauth-php project or oauth PECL extension.